# how can i give multiple inputs in blender game engine using logic-bricks

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

i am new in blender so please anyone help me to know that how can i provide two inputs in blender game as in dijkstra algorithm one input for source and another for destination to tell the distance between them.

when i am giving input in source then the text field of destination is field automatically with same value as of source so the generated output is 0 at every time.

Logic-bricks of source 
[image]

logic-bricks of destination
[image]

logic-bricks of distance[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that i assing the values to a persist in bge.logic attribute, also if you have 2 messages sensor waiting for the same subject you will recive always the same value, to have 2 inputs you need that only 1 state active as input so in state_1 only text_1 has a keyboard sensor and text_2 has no sensors while in state 2 the the text_2 has a keyboard sensor ans text_1 has no sensors, to change the state use a `keyboard sensor key RETURN`+`and controller`+`state actuator` to change the states.

**Option 1:**

[image]

```
from bge import logic

scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
cont = logic.getCurrentController()

if not hasattr(logic,'value1'):
    logic.value1 = int(cont.sensors['Message'].bodies[0])
elif not hasattr(logic,'value2'):
    logic.value2 = int(cont.sensors['Message.001'].bodies[0])

scene.objects['result']['Text'] = logic.value1 + logic.value2
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Option 2: #######################################################**

[image]

```
from bge import logic

scene = logic.getCurrentScene()

def waiting_inputs(controller):
    if not hasattr(logic,'value1'):
        scene.objects['hint']['Text'] = 'Enter value 1:'
        input = scene.objects['input']
        logic.value1 = int(input['Text'])
        input['Text'] = 'Here'
        return
    elif not hasattr(logic,'value2'):
        scene.objects['hint']['Text'] = 'Enter value 2:'
        input = scene.objects['input']
        logic.value2 = int(input['Text'])
    else:
        showOutput()

def showOutput():
    scene.objects['result']['Text'] = logic.value1 + logic.value2
```

[image]

[image]

**Option 3: #######################################################**

```
from bge import logic

scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
cont = logic.getCurrentController()

if not hasattr(logic,'value1'):
    logic.value1 = int(cont.sensors['Message'].bodies[0])
elif not hasattr(logic,'value2'):
    scene.objects['hint']['Text'] = 'Enter value 2:'
    logic.value2 = int(cont.sensors['Message'].bodies[0])

scene.objects['result']['Text'] = logic.value1) + logic.value2
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your support and time which you spend to solve this problem

Comment: If this totally answer your question please consider accepting it as an answer.