# How do I make editable text in the Game Engine?

Tags: python, game-engine, text-object

I am making a "game" in the Blender Game Engine which requires some editable text. The game is basically a fake operating system with a photo editor and text editor so far.

I tried using the text string property and linked it to the keyboard sensor with all keys enabled. This works okay but the text box properties don't apply to the game engine so the text just goes on in one direction instead of wrapping.

I also tried using the following Python script:

```
import bge
from bge import logic, events

def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    keyEvents = logic.keyboard.events

    hitKey = [k for k in keyEvents \
                    if keyEvents[k] == logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED]

    if hitKey != []:
        print(hitKey)
        characterValue = bge.events.EventToCharacter(hitKey[0], True)
        print(characterValue)
        own ["userInput"] += characterValue

    own.text = own ["userInput"]

main()
```

I got most of the way through the process of making the script but for some reason while playing the game my keyboard input doesn't affect the text. I had all the right properties, names, etc.

Is something wrong with my code? Also, if possible is there a way to use the text box in the game engine?

Comment: I figured out that the script works when the always sensor is set to pulse mode. However the backspace and delete keys display a ! symbol.

Comment: Thats because you are converting the ascii code to a character and adding it to the string. You just neet to set up the correctly the text object and instead using ``EventToCharacter`` put a keyboard sensor. take a look to [how can i give multiple inputs in blender game engine using logic-bricks](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95003/how-can-i-give-multiple-inputs-in-blender-game-engine-using-logic-bricks/95044#95044)